# What information can I get from this report that might help me track down a crash?

Tags: android, crash, stack-trace

Users are reporting crashes at startup, but I have not been able to recreate the crash. I have received several stack traces as below. What can I learn from the stack trace?

> ```
> Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hltespr/hltespr:4.4.2/KOT49H/N900PVPUCNC5:user/release-keys'
> Revision: '8'
> pid: 8793, tid: 8793, name: myco.myapp >>> com.myco.myapp <<<
> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000058
> r0 7e3aab78 r1 7a2fbf10 r2 00000059 r3 00000001
> r4 7e3aab78 r5 be97e2fc r6 00932c58 r7 772d67f8
> r8 be97e358 r9 6d666a44 sl 416bcc18 fp be97e36c
> ip 403bdad8 sp be97e2f8 lr 40d9ae09 pc 00000058 cpsr 60050030
> d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
> d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
> d4 4462e00044834000 d5 430f000000000000
> d6 430d000000000000 d7 0000000000000000
> d8 00000000435a9ab8 d9 4250000000000000
> d10 4250000000000034 d11 0000000000000000
> d12 0000000000000000 d13 40c556c1e63b7acf
> d14 3fe0000000000000 d15 fffffbe84359e388
> d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
> d18 0000000000000000 d19 0000000000000000
> d20 0000000000000000 d21 0000000000000000
> d22 000000003f800000 d23 3f80000000000000
> d24 4000000000000000 d25 0000000000000000
> d26 3ff0000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
> d28 4000000000000000 d29 c084e80000000000
> d30 fff0000000000000 d31 ffffffff00000000
> scr 68000013
>
> backtrace:
> #00 pc 00000058 <unknown>
> #01 pc 00025e07 /system/lib/libhwui.so
> #02 pc 00026009 /system/lib/libhwui.so
> #03 pc 00026039 /system/lib/libhwui.so
> #04 pc 0001ddd5 /system/lib/libhwui.so
> #05 pc 0006bab7 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
> #06 pc 00020bcc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
> #07 pc 00051927 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
> #08 pc 0002a060 /system/lib/libdvm.so
> #09 pc 00031510 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
> #10 pc 0002eba8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
> #11 pc 00064159 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
> #12 pc 0006c1bf /system/lib/libdvm.so
> #13 pc 0002a060 /system/lib/libdvm.so
> #14 pc 00031510 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
> #15 pc 0002eba8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
> #16 pc 00063e75 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
> #17 pc 0004d457 /system/lib/libdvm.so
> #18 pc 0005203f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
> #19 pc 000535d3 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
> #20 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
> #21 pc 0000e513 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
> #22 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process
>
> code around pc:
> 00000038 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000048 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000058 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000068 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000078 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000088 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000098 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 000000a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 000000b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 000000c8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 000000d8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 000000e8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 000000f8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000108 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000118 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
> 00000128 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
>
> code around lr:
> 40d9ade8 44794633 f7e7447a 6860e9f0 f7eab120 
> 40d9adf8 6861fc41 fdd3f7ec 46206821 4790684a 
> 40d9ae08 f7ff4628 bdfefef5 0000b8ba 0000cc78 
> 40d9ae18 0000b89e 0000ccab f7ff6811 0000bfb5 
> 40d9ae28 4607b5f0 6808b08b f844ac0a b1100d18 
> 40d9ae38 f7e74621 4829e88c f7ff4478 9b04fc7f 
> 40d9ae48 a808aa07 a9099200 aa059001 68d89102 
> 40d9ae58 ab066919 fe32f7ff 9e089804 7a05eddd 
> 40d9ae68 ed9d9d09 69430a06 0a07eddd 7a10edc3 
> 40d9ae78 0a11ed83 0a12edc3 615d611e 429668fa 
> 40d9ae88 4295d81a 2028d818 e89cf7e7 f7e74605 
> 40d9ae98 9b04eebe 0a05ed9d eddd9a09 ed9d0a06 
> 40d9aea8 92001a07 68d8462a 9b086919 fbdcf7ff 
> 40d9aeb8 68889904 e0046145 61192100 68806159 
> 40d9aec8 30046141 fac0f7e8 21002008 f8bcf7e9 
> 40d9aed8 f7ff4620 b00bfe8d bf00bdf0 0000cc70
> ```